# WP rocket prevent 301 redirect to URL with trailing slash

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

When user access to my website with url:

*example.com/post-name*

Wordpress should perform 301 redirect to:

*example.com/post-name/*

But it's not working due the WP Rocket caching plugin *(I couldn't find out why this is happening, but WP rocket is definitely causing problem)*

Is it okay to perform [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) to url with trailing slash?
Is there any other solution except **.htaccess** redirect?

Comment: What is set as your permalink structure in WordPress? (Settings -> Permalinks). Does that include a trailing slash?

You can try to re-save that one and flush the WP-Rocket cache after that.

Comment: yes, it includes trailing slash

Comment: the wp_redirect is very expensive way of doing any redirection!! if you really need to do redirection better use .htaccess!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent any intervention from WordPress and/or plugins, you could try forcing trailing slashes through .htaccess (Apache):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-json/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*[^\/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 
</IfModule>
```

The RewriteRule matches any path *without* a trailing slash through mod_rewrite (if enabled) and redirects to that same path *with* a trailing slash.

The RewriteCond exclude paths in the `/wp-json/` and `wp-admin/` folder, as well as paths with dots, indicating files with an extension (e.g. `.jpg`, `.css` etc).

Forcing a trailing slash in the `/wp-json/` and `wp-admin/` folders can cause problems in the WordPress admin panel and with Full Site Editing.

Comment: Thanks, but what about site assets like img & css files they can't be loaded with trailing slash

Comment: @bagli Edited the above to specify the exclusion of files (paths with dots).

Comment: Thanks, think it will solve my problem

Comment: Okay, if it's correct, please mark this as the correct answer.